# Existing results around approximation of minimum 2-edge connected Steiner subgraph

Tags: graph-theory, approximation-algorithms, parameterized-complexity

**Problem $1$: minimum 2-edge connected subgraph**

> We are given a [$2$-edge connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-edge-connected_graph) undirected graph $G(V,E)$, and we are asked to find a $\textit{spanning}$ subgraph $H$, with minimum number of edges, such that $H$ is $2
> $-edge connected.

There is a result by [Jothi et. al.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjptqeq66X2AhW9S_EDHXOIB_UQFnoECDkQAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.du.edu%2F%7Esnarayan%2Fsada%2Fresearch%2Fdocs%2Fp725-jothi.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2SL7d0lxTNAMLBWS914Jcq) that there exists a $\frac{5}{4}$ approximation for the problem $1$.

Following is the generalized version of the problem above:

**Problem $2$: minimum 2-edge connected Steiner subgraph**

> We are given a [$2$-edge connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-edge-connected_graph) undirected graph $G(V,E)$, and a subset of vertices $T\subseteq V$, and we are asked to find a subgraph $H$, with minimum number of edges, such that $H$ is $2$-edge connected and $T \in H$ (ie. $H$ may not contain some (or all) vertices from $V \backslash T$).

Are there any results around approximability (or in-approximability) for the problem $2$, for ***general*** graphs?
On searching online most of the papers I came across either talk about "descriptions" of the related polytope or approximation schemes when graphs are restricted to special classes eg planar graphs, etc.

Comment: Yes, your problem is a special case of the much more general problem called the Survivable Network Design Problem (SNDP). It admits a 2-approximation. See books on approximation by Vazirani (Chapter 23) and Williamson-Shmoys (Chapter 11).